# On change of account owner, it should send an email to old owner and new owner

Tags: email, workflow, email-template

Hie ,

I want to send an email to the old owner as well as the new owner as soon as the owner of the record changes.

But  with workflow i am able to send the email to current owner.

Please suggest me a way to send the email to the old owner as well

Best Regards,
Ankita

Answer (score 4):

Ankita,

In workflow, you will not find the old value. Trigger is the way to achieve it. By using Trigger.old you can have the old value and fire an email if its changed.

Comment: isn't their any other way to achieve this w/o using trigger?

Comment: @Ankita, workflow,formula everything will hold the current value/new value. Via trigger you can achieve this.

Comment: Can this not be done with a simple Workflow rule and an email alert?
(using the  PRIORVALUE function )

Comment: No PriorValue() Function is used in formula criteria, we can not use priorvalue() formula function as recipient of email.

Answer (score 1):

write an after update trigger
Capture the values from old and new maps
Write class to send email using MEsssaging class